# How to calculate class-wise accuracy of Semantic Segmentation Model in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, semantic-segmentation

I want to calculate the class-wise pixel accuracy of my semantic segmentation model. Currently, I am computing MIoU using sklearn metrics (as shown in the code snippet below). I shall be grateful If anyone helps me out.

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7s0s.png)

Comment: Why do you want to calculate pixel-wise accuracy instead of Dice Score or IoU? It can mislead you for segmentation tasks.

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/metrics-to-evaluate-your-semantic-segmentation-model-6bcb99639aa2 Look at this, please.